# Can't get data from file input / html php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, file, input

I'm trying to understand how input type file works, how to store the file with php form and then insert it into my database. Here is my form:

```
<form action="../src/add.php" class="addform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="addform__group mb-20">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nom de l'artiste" name="artist" class="form-control mr-30">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Titre" name="title" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="addform__group mb-20">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Label" name="label" class="form-control mr-30">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Vocaliste" name="vocal" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="addform__group mb-20">
        <select name="genre" id="genre" class="form-control mr-30" style="width: 282px;">
            <?php

                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>

                    <option value="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>"><?php echo $row["name"] ?></option>
                
            <?php } ?>
        </select>

        <input type="date" id="date-picker" class="form-control" name="created-at">
    </div>

    <!-- Upload audio and image -->
    <div class="addform__group mb-20" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
        <div>
            <input type="file" id="audio" name="audio">
            <label for="audio"><i class="fas fa-music mr-10"></i> Audio (jpg)</label>
            <label id="audio-name"></label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="file" id="image" name="image">
            <label for="image"><i class="fas fa-image mr-10"></i> Image (jpg)</label>
            <label id="image-name"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="addform__group">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Ajouter</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the process I use in php (add.php):

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    // Get the data from the form
    $artiste = $_POST["artist"];
    $title = $_POST["title"];
    $label = $_POST["label"];
    $vocal = $_POST["vocal"];
    $genre = $_POST["genre"];
    $date = $_POST["created-at"];
    $audio = $_FILES["audio"]["name"];
    $image = $_FILES["image"]["name"];


    // Query to insert a new music
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `music` (`artist`, `title`, `label`, `vocal`, `genre_id`, `created_at`, `audio`, `image`) VALUES ('$artiste', '$title', '$label', '$vocal', '$genre', '$date', '$audio', '$image')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    // Check result and errors
    if($result) {
        echo 'Musique ajoutée';
    } else {
        echo 'Erreur: ' . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

    // Upload image file in a directory
    $imageDir = "../upload/img/";
    $imageFile = $imageDir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $imageFile)) {
        echo "Image uploaded";
    } else {
        echo "Image not uploaded";
    }

    // Upload audio file in a directory
    $audioDir = "../upload/audio/";
    $audioFile = $audioDir . basename($_FILES["audio"]["name"]);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["audio"]["tmp_name"], $audioFile)) {
        echo "Audio uploaded";
    } else {
        echo "Audio not uploaded";
    }

}
```

The problem is when I send the form, I get a blank page. I tried to test all the inputs and "audio" is the problem, $_FILES["audio"]["name"] returns empty.

Everything works fine with the image, I can get the name of the image and even save the image in the specified folder.

That's what I get if I var_dump($_FILES) when uploading ONLY image, if I upload an audio I have the blank page as usual.

```
array (size=2)
  'audio' => 
    array (size=6)
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'full_path' => string '' (length=0)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => int 4
      'size' => int 0
  'image' => 
    array (size=6)
      'name' => string 'koven-lionsvip.jpg' (length=18)
      'full_path' => string 'koven-lionsvip.jpg' (length=18)
      'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp64\tmp\php2C50.tmp' (length=25)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 50412
```

Uploading a new item with empty "audio" works well and is stored in the database, the audio input makes it not working

Anyone have an idea? I guess I made a mistake in the code but I can't find it after several hours of searching. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check `$_FILES["audio"]['error']`

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string.

Comment: This process is described quite well [In the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) including the error checking

Comment: Audio files tend to be larger than images, I would guess you will need to amend the file size allowed to be uploaded by PHP in the `php.ini` file

Comment: $_FILES["audio"]['error'] displays nothing, even $_FILES["audio"] does the same. I know about SQL Injection but this is a personal project and it will be used only on my localhost. I'll check what you sent me and edit my post later, thank you !

Comment: Not sure why you haev 2 labels for the image and audio?

Comment: `I know about SQL Injection but this is a personal project and it will be used only on my localhost`...ok but 1) prepared statements aren't difficult and it's easier not to make mistakes with those, 2) there's no reason not to do things properly every time, and 3) Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. There's simply no reason _not_ to use them!

Comment: Also, bring your error-handling into the 21st century: add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically without you needing to write lots of repetitive code to check for errors after every mysqli command.

Comment: The labels "audio-name" and "image-name" are used to display the file name when I selected it with javascript, isn't it a right way to achieve it?

Comment: A label is [used to label an input field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). Use span or div or whatever for general content

Comment: Anyway, it's strange that you see nothing at all for the audio field. Run `var_dump($_FILES);` and show us what's in it. You can also use your browser's Network tool to see what's being uploaded when the form is submitted, and check whether the "audio" field content is there.

Comment: I agree with you about prepared statements, I made a mistake and I will update it asap. I updated my topic with the var_dump($_FILES)

Comment: The solution was to increase the file size in php.ini. Thank you for your quick help and your precious advices, I am not a regular user of php

Comment: Great! But please put the answer in the Answers section below, it does not belong as part of the question! Take the [tour] if you're unsure how the question and answer format works here. There's also [answer]. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

for those who would encounter the same problem, the solution was to increase the size allowed for file upload in the php.ini file.

"upload_max_filesize" and "post_max_size"